# How to use intersection observer polyfill with Vue cli 3?

Tags: vue.js, intersection-observer

How to use: https://github.com/w3c/IntersectionObserver/tree/master/polyfill

Should i load it in a webpack config - vue.config.js or should i load it in a .vue template using imports?

Comment: did you figure this out? i thought babel/core-js which is built in to the vue-cli is suppose to  handle this.

Comment: Intersectional Observer is a browser-only feature and is not provided in core-js. https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/issues/386

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install intersection-observer
```

Add this line to the top of your entry file (such as `main.js`)

```
import 'intersection-observer/intersection-observer';
```

That's all.